# What is the equivalent of field_view_field()?

Tags: views, 9

I am working on some code where I need to get some fields from a node. For the body, I want to display the summary, or the trimmed body if the summary is not there.

I found an example on the web using field_view_field(), which seems to do what I want it to do: return the body field using the summary_or_trimmed formatter.  But it seems this is a Drupal 7 thing.  I can't seem to figure out what or if there is an equivalent.

The Drupal 7 example went something like this:

```
$x1 =  field_view_field('node', $node, 'body', 
                                array('label'=>'hidden',
                                      'type' => 'text_summary_or_trimmed',
                                      'settings'=>array('trim_length' => 50)));
```

Note: I am trying to assemble text output for an email.  I thought I could do this by making a custom display view mode, 'alt-teaser', that is like 'teaser' for my content type, but I don't see a way to get rid of the title (!), which I do not want.
So that is why I now hope to get at individual fields, formatted.

```
 $viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
 $renderArray = $viewBuilder->view($node, 'alt_teaser');
```

Comment: Here is what worked for me (using d9)  

 $body = $node->body[0]->view('alt_teaser');
 $display = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($body);  
 Thank you cilefen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal's change records usually indicate when an API has been removed or changed. This one is documented: https://www.drupal.org/node/2208327

> In Drupal 8, those functions have been replaced by view() methods on, respectively, the FieldItemList object (i.e $entity->field_name, "the list of field items") and the FieldItem object (i.e. $entity->field_name[$delta], a specific item in the list). Their signatures have also been largely simplified.